# Use context to break out of a loop

Tags: go, go-context

Consider this (https://play.golang.org/p/zvDiwul9QR0):

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("Done")
            break
        default:
            for {
                fmt.Println("loop")
                time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

So here the contexts returns a "Done()" channel after 2 seconds. And I want to catch this and cancel my infinite for loop. The code example above does not do this, it never exits the loop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: in general issue is in your example


  default:
            for {
                fmt.Println("loop")
                time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond)
            }
        }


you have internal second loop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Context cancelation is not magic - it's just a signal mechanism. To abort work, you still need to monitor the state of the `context` from within your worker goroutine:

```
func myTask(ctx context.Context, poll time.Duration) error {                 
    ticker := time.NewTicker(poll)
    defer ticker.Stop()
                                                                 
    for {                                                                      
        fmt.Println("loop")                                                      
        select {                                                                 
        case <-ticker.C:
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return ctx.Err()
        }                                                                        
    }                                                                          
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/s6dSr9qqKJU

---

also as Eli pointed out, `break` will only break out of the select statement - so you need something more precise to break out of a loop. Refactoring into functions make `return`'s much more intuitive for task abortion.

---

Following up from comments. I would refactor your task like so:

```
// any potentially blocking task should take a context
// style: context should be the first passed in parameter
func myTask(ctx context.Context, poll time.Duration) error {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(poll)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for {
        fmt.Println("loop")
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return ctx.Err()
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So I will need to embed another select statement in my loop?

Comment: @FelixRosén I've updated the answer on how stylistically one should write a task that takes a context.

Comment: your example has issue - you will use 100500% of CPU with this approach because  SELECT is not blocked operation

Comment: @okhrypko you would only see this if the `poll` value is `0` - which is not a very good polling interval! Any non-zero value, the `select` statement will block waiting for the the timer to fire (provided the context is not `done`)